# Linux Sed -e argument

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following command in my backup rotate script to remove old backups. It works as it ensure the latest backup is retained.

```
ls -t | sed -e '1,1d' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

I'm unsure of the `sed -e` argument is doing though. When I check `man sed` I get:

> -e script, --expression=script
>
> ```
>           add the script to the commands to be executed
> ```

I can't find details of what my current script argument `'1,1d'` is attempting to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d`elete lines `1` to `1`.  It just removes the first line.

For testing, type:

```
seq 10
```

vs.

```
seq 10 | sed -e '1,1d'
```

Answer (score 4):

`-e script` is adding the script to the sed-command-list. `script`  is used here as synonym for string, in difference to script-file in the option `-f script-file`. That's why the argument is usually put into quotes (which could be omitted here). The script/string may inlcude a sequence of commands.

You may use more then one `-e '<sed-cmd>'`, which are then applied to the input line in sequence. For example `sed -e 's/kitty/cat/g' -e 's/cat/lion/g'`. Sometimes it is easier to understand where all the lions came from.

`d` is one of the commands which accept address ranges. `1,1` is the address range, here from line 1 to line1, which could be shortened to `1d`